# How to share data between classes?

Tags: c#, textures, data-sharing

I want to make a class which defines a level in a game. It's got to have an access to the data(textures) which is used by a main game class. How can I do it?

```
namespace xnagame
{

class Level
{
  blockTexture1, blockTexture2;
  Content.RootDirectory = "Content"; 
   void LoadTextures()
    { 
      blockTexture1 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("textures/block1");
      blockTexture2 = Content.Load<Texture2D>("textures/block2");
    }
}
```

There is the picture of my project below. I need to get an access from the class "Level" to the data stored in "xnagameContent/textures" http://cs403723.userapi.com/v403723602/5635/Pq5jGApDYCU.jpg

Comment: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/csharpobjectoriented.aspx

Comment: Nice link LB, thank for sharing.

Comment: Perhaps a static class with a get\set property for each of the textures you want might be a good idea?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an ideal case for [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). You could pass in a reference to your `Content` class in your constructor or make it a public property e.g.

```
public class Level
{
    public Level(Content content)
    {
        Content = content;
    }

    public Content Content { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

**main method:**

```
Level level = new xnagame.Level(this.Content);
level.LoadTextures();
```

**custom Level class:**

```
namespace xnagame
{
    public class Level
    {
        public Texture2D blockTexture1, 
        public Texture2D blockTexture2;
        public ContentManager content;

        public Level(ContentManager content)
        {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public void LoadTextures()
        {
            this.blockTexture1 = this.content.Load<Texture2D>("textures/block1");
            this.blockTexture2 = this.content.Load<Texture2D>("textures/block2");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe that is the question! I don't know what type my parameter type should be. There is no such type as "Content". It is a namespace!

Comment: updated my answer .. that might not be perfect but it should steer you in the right direction

Comment: you might have better luck posting on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com .. they have a tag for "xna"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a xna expert but I think that Xna ContentManager object is available if you derive your class from Game. Content is a property of the Game class. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb203875.aspx

If you want to separate the loading code and put it in the Level class you can pass an instance of a ContentManager obtained using the Content property of the main game class.

Comment: It'd work but, it'd use many resources I don't want to use. It's got to be easier because the only thing I need is to get access to data.